# Wrap each word in an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Is there an algorithm/library for taking any html document, finding all the 'words' (single words) in the document and the wrapping each word inside a span (or any other html element). I am using angularJS framework which has some jQuery restrictions. Still, even with jQuery i cannot seem to get it to work. I used the .contents().filter().wrap() mechanism outlined on the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). However it is only useful when I want to wrap entire lines of text rather than the individual words. This problem is very frustrating and I would truly appreciate some help. Thanks much!

Okay sorry for the lack of details previously.

My application pulls a string from a database. The string is contains html. I created a custom directive named 'spanner' and bound this directive to the html string on the scope like so:

Inside my directive I try to add a span around each word in the html like so:

```
.directive('spanner', function($compile){
var linkFn = function(scope, element, attributes)
{
    element.append(scope.spanner);
    angular.forEach(element.find('*').contents(), function(val, key){
        var a = angular.element(val);
        var text;
        if(a.context.nodeType === 3)
        {
            text = a.text();
            text = text.split(' ');
            angular.forEach(text, function(val, key){
                if(key%2 === 0){
                    val = "<span class='even'>" + val + "</span>";
                }
                else
                {
                    val = "<span ng-class='odd'>" + val + "</span>";
                }
                text[key] = val;
            });

            text = text.join(' ');              
        }
        a.html(text);
        element.find('*').contents()[key] = a;            
    });
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};

return {
    scope: {
        spanner: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFn
};

});
```

Comment: For what reason do you want to wrap every word in an element? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in the question. Show us what you have tried and what you think the problem is.

Comment: You will need to rely on string manipulation. 1) get your content 2) split on word (using a Regular Expression or just by splitting apart at the spaces) 3) wrap each word in a span 4) re-insert into your document. The specific implementation will depend on the structure of your app. Like the other commenters said, some source code would help you get a better answer out of Stack Overflow.

Comment: If your input are only strings, the highlight filter in ui.utils package http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/highlight is what you are looking for.

Comment: I made an update to the original question. Please note that the html document contains a tree of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/rUX4c/)**

```
var text = $.trim($('p').text()),
    word = text.split(' '),
    str = "";
$.each( word, function( key, value ) {
  if(key != 0) { str += " "; }
  str += "<span>" + value + "</span>";
});
$('p').html(str);
```

*The big question that remains is how are you going to handle punctuation? -- I'll leave that to you to figure out*

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/xudis/1/edit

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
 var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" "); 

  angular.forEach(res, function(word){

    word = "<span>" + word + "<span>";
    console.log(word);


  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using jQuery in angular and this is done in a directive can do something like:

```
link: function( scope, elem, attrs){
  elem.html(function( _, original){
       var words = original.split(' ');
       return '<span class="wrap">' + words.join('</span><span class="wrap">') +'</span>';
   });    
}
```

Also assumes element contains only text