# JavaScript span element on each individual word

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to create a function that accepts two parameters a selector and a string which will put each individual word within the text content of the selected element inside a new 'span' element. Each new 'span' element must be given a unique ID, formed by combining the prefix and a sequential integer (e.g. par0, par1 etc.). Also the function needs to handle the nested child elements...

Any help of creating this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So what did you try? Split on word boundry/space and loop over the list and wrap in span with the id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786071/wrap-each-word-in-an-html-element or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609170/how-to-wrap-each-word-of-an-element-in-a-span-tag or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105059/how-to-wrap-all-text-into-unique-span-tag or tons of other questions

Comment: the output would be <span>word1</span><span>word2</span> etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery it is not to hard. Something like this should work:

```
var sentence = "this is a sentence";
var words = sentence.split(" ");

$.each(words, function(i, w){
    $("#elementToAppendTo").append($("<span>").text(w));
});
```

Split the sentence by " " (space). The split function returns an array.

Iterate over the words array and for every word, rap it in a span element and then append to a certain html element with the id "elementToAppendTo".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.

First you need to select the DOM elements with document.querySelectorAll then iterate over the elements with the [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, this uses [regex](http://www.rexegg.com/) to capture any words and replace them with the template (this being a span wrapper).

```js
function doThing(selector, str) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach((element) => {
      element.innerHTML = str.replace(/(\w+)/g, `<span>$1</span>`);
    });
}

doThing('.latin', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.');
```

```css
span {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="latin"></div>
```

Comment: it's return only the first ID and delete the remain text... further information is  no span elements in the HTML.

Comment: @lolek please can you show your current workings to further understand you problem?